# How print numbers to a word table using python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

Hello I am trying to put numbers into a word table in python, however I am unable to this, I can only add strings. I am using the library python docx. I want to populate a word docmument with the contents of k and j, how can I do this?

Python code

```
from docx import Document

p= document.add_paragraph('Hello world!')

k=(1,2,3,982,5,5)
j=(2,3,4,1,2,33)

table = document.add_table(rows=5,cols=5)
num=table.cell(1,3)
num.text="Hello"
#num.text=k[0]
```

The output I receive is hello where expected. But now I want to place the values in my array in a table but now when I un-comment the area placing k[0] in the same place I get the following error.

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `.text` attribute is looking for a string. So you need to convert the number to a string first. I would probably do this:

```
num.text = '%d' % k[0]
```

... but there are a number of ways to convert numbers to strings, like `str(k[0])`, etc.

In Python, a string is an iterable object, conceptually it's much like a tuple with single character elements. That's why you're getting the somewhat puzzling error message having to do with being iterable.